# How to get an ManyToManyField related queryset that can be iterated in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

lets say my **models.py** looks like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Review(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='review_tags', blank=True)
```

In my **views.py** I am getting a queryset like this:

```
def index(request):
    reviews = Review.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {'reviews' : reviews})
```

Now in **index.html**, I am doing something like this:

```
<div>
    {% for review in reviews %}
        <p>{{review.text}}</p>
        {% for tag in review.tags %}
            {{tag.name}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Obviously, this does not work. However, it gives you an idea of what I am trying to do, that is, get the tags for a particular review and just display them. How do I do this with my current setup?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am completely rewrited the answer, because it get upvotes and 'accepted answer', however initially it was wrong.

So the right answer would be to call `{% for tag in review.tags.all %}` to iterate through all `Tag` objects that relate to `Review` object in loop.

**Adition**: if you want firstly iterate though `Tag` objects and then iterate through `Review` objects that has a relation with `Tag` then you need to have view, that returns `Tag` objects.

```
def index(request):
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'tags': tags})
```

And in the template you need to iterate using `related_name` in `ManyToManyField`

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    <p>{{tag.name}}</p>
    {% for review in tag.review_tags.all %}
        {{ review.text }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This does not work for some reason. I tried {% for tag in review.review_tags.all %} {{tag.name}} {% endfor %}, but nothing displays.

Comment: However, {% for tag in review.tags.all %} does work. Thanks.

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee thank you, i rewrited the answer, so now it has correct info.